# How to get distinct values of a column by finding max timestamp for each and then get rest of the columns as well

Tags: excel, macros, oracle12c

I have a big oracle(Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0) table say table_name which is updated every 15 seconds. 
It has many columns but ones I am concerned are:

```
Name            Null?    Type                              
--------------- -------- --------------------------------- 
ID_1            NOT NULL NUMBER(38)                        
UTC_TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE       
ID_2                     VARCHAR2(8)                       
SERVER_NAME              VARCHAR2(256)                     
ID_3                     NUMBER(38)                        
COUNT_1                  NUMBER(38)                        
COUNT_2                  NUMBER(38)
```

**What I am trying to do is:**

1) Get all the records where UTC_TIMESTAMP <= current_date and UTC_TIMESTAMP > current_date - 5 minute (there are around 125K-150K)

2) This data will have duplicate ID_1. So I want to take only those records where each ID_1 had max(UTC_TIMESTAMP) among it's duplicates. So now we'll have distinct ID_1.

**What I have tried:** Using the following SQL

```
with temp_1 as (
select m.ID_2, m.ID_1, max(utc_timestamp) max_utc_timestamp
   from commsdesk.table_name m
   where m.ID_2 = 'TWC'
   group by m.ID_2, m.ID_1)
select f.utc_timestamp
  from commsdesk.table_name f
  join temp_1 t
    on t.max_utc_timestamp = f.utc_timestamp
   and t.ID_2 = f.ID_2
   and t.ID_1 = f.ID_1;
```

**Problem:** I can get only ID_2, ID_1 and UTC_TIMESTAMP but I want all the other columns as well.
Can it be done using SQL?

There are around 2200 distinct ID_1 and around 125K-150K records in a 5 minute window. 
So doing it by copying the 125K-150K records in excel sheet and filtering on each of the 2200 ID_1 to find max of UTC_TIMESTAMP for each ID_1 in impractical.
But I can do that as well if there is any quick way to do it using macro.

Sample dummy data:

```
ID_2    SERVER_NAME     ID_3    ID_1     UTC_TIMESTAMP               COUNT_1    COUNT_2
ABC     PQRS.ABC.TPO    2       303      24-JUL-17 03.41.55.000000000 PM +00:00 4   0
ABC     PQRS.ABC.TPO    2      1461      24-JUL-17 03.42.48.000000000 PM +00:00 1   7
ABC     PQRS.ABC.TPO    2         1      24-JUL-17 03.41.36.000000000 PM +00:00 2   3
ABC    PQRS.ABC.TPO     2      1461      24-JUL-17 03.41.16.000000000 PM +00:00 0   8
ABC    PQRS.ABC.TPO     1         1      24-JUL-17 03.41.11.000000000 PM +00:00 5   0
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      1         1      24-JUL-17 03.41.23.000000000 PM +00:00 0   0
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      2       303      24-JUL-17 03.41.34.000000000 PM +00:00 0   0
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      2      1461      24-JUL-17 03.41.31.000000000 PM +00:00 0   0
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      4       303      24-JUL-17 03.41.26.000000000 PM +00:00 4   8
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      2       303      24-JUL-17 03.41.20.000000000 PM +00:00 0   0
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      1      1461      24-JUL-17 03.41.01.000000000 PM +00:00 3   8
ABC    SRP.ROP.MTP      4         1      24-JUL-17 03.41.18.000000000 PM +00:00 9   1
```

Expected output:

```
ID_1    UTC_TIMESTAMP                           COUNT_1 COUNT_2
1       24-JUL-17 03.41.36.000000000 PM +00:00  2       3
303     24-JUL-17 03.41.55.000000000 PM +00:00  4       0
1461    24-JUL-17 03.42.48.000000000 PM +00:00  1       7
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have any duplicates, based on the rules you've sort of explained. Please show some representative sample data *and* the result you expect for that data.

Comment: I have updated sample data and added the expected output. Sorry for delay in response but I didn't have access to data over weekend. After I can get the expected output, I would use it as sub query to get MAX(UTC_TIMESTAMP) and SUM(COUNT_1) AND SUM(COUNT_2) from the expected output.

Comment: the query I first posted gets that result; I've updated my answer to show that.I'm not sure what you mean about a subquery though. Are you ultimately looking for a single result with `24-JUL-17 03.42.48`, 7, 10` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for as final result. I am using your query and will post the outcome here.  Thank you again.

Comment: The updated solution works exactly as I wanted it but when I tried to validate the output by manually doing the calculations, the numbers are different. In my example the SQL gave "51 2434" when the manual validation gives "199 2679". But I have no way to share entire data that I used for this use case. And it might be something in data as well. So I am marking your response as answer.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Excel, what is the excel problem at hand? If none, then please remove the Excel tag.

Comment: I was open for a excel/macro solution as well. That is why I added that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `keep (dense_rank last ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm#SQLRF00653) version of the `max()` aggregate function (or, if you prefer, `first` and `min`), something like:

```
select id_1,
  max(utc_timestamp),
  max(id_2) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as id_2,
  max(server_name) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as server_name,
  max(id_3) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as id_3,
  max(count_1) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_1,
  max(count_2) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_2
from table_name
where utc_timestamp > current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
and utc_timestamp <= current_timestamp
group by id_1
order by id_1;
```

The query is grouped by `id_1`, and as you want the latest timestamp the `max(utc_timestamp)` is 'normal'. The other columns keep the value that is associated with the row which has that maximum timestamp, for the `id_`.

With some dummy data:

```
insert into table_name (id_1, utc_timestamp, id_2, server_name, id_3, count_1, count_2)
values (1, systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' - interval '30' second, 'TWC', 'test1', 301, 1, 1);
insert into table_name (id_1, utc_timestamp, id_2, server_name, id_3, count_1, count_2)
values (1, systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' - interval '60' second, 'TWC', 'test2', 302, 2, 2);
insert into table_name (id_1, utc_timestamp, id_2, server_name, id_3, count_1, count_2)
values (1, systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' - interval '90' second, 'TWC', 'test3', 303, 3, 3);
insert into table_name (id_1, utc_timestamp, id_2, server_name, id_3, count_1, count_2)
values (2, systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' - interval '45' second, 'TWC', 'test4', 304, 4, 4);
insert into table_name (id_1, utc_timestamp, id_2, server_name, id_3, count_1, count_2)
values (2, systimestamp at time zone 'UTC' - interval '15' second, 'TWC', 'test5', 305, 5, 5);
```

that query gets the result:

```
      ID_1 MAX(UTC_TIMESTAMP)          ID_2     SERVE       ID_3    COUNT_1    COUNT_2
---------- --------------------------- -------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-07-21 18:38:22.944 UTC TWC      test1        301          1          1
         2 2017-07-21 18:38:38.399 UTC TWC      test5        305          5          5
```

---

You could get the same result with something more like your attempt:

```
with cte as (
  select id_1, max(utc_timestamp) max_utc_timestamp
  from table_name m
  where utc_timestamp > current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
  and utc_timestamp <= current_timestamp
  group by id_1
)
select t.id_1, t.utc_timestamp, t.id_2, t.server_name, t.id_3, t.count_1, t.count_2
from cte
join table_name t on t.id_1 = cte.id_1
and t.utc_timestamp = cte.max_utc_timestamp
order by t.id_1;
```

... assuming the `id_1` and `utc_timestamp` combination is unique (not sure why you were using `id_2` for the join; maybe that is needed for uniqueness?). But that will be less efficient as it has to query the real table twice, once to find the maximum timestamp for each `id_1`, and then again in the join. It's probably worth running both versions to compare the results and timings, and the execution plans.

---

With your sample data (as updated on 2017-07-24), the first query above - modified just to use a fixed timestamp range to match - gets:

```
     ID_1 MAX(UTC_TIMESTAMP)                ID_ SERVER_NAME        ID_3    COUNT_1    COUNT_2
---------- --------------------------------- --- ------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-07-24 15:41:36.000000 +00:00 ABC PQRS.ABC.TPO          2          2          3
       303 2017-07-24 15:41:55.000000 +00:00 ABC PQRS.ABC.TPO          2          4          0
      1461 2017-07-24 15:42:48.000000 +00:00 ABC PQRS.ABC.TPO          2          1          7
```

or taking out the columns you don't seem to be interested in:

```
select id_1,
  max(utc_timestamp),
  max(count_1) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_1,
  max(count_2) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_2
from table_name
where utc_timestamp > timestamp '2017-07-24 16:40:00 Europe/London' -- current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
and utc_timestamp <= timestamp '2017-07-24 16:45:00 Europe/London' -- current_timestamp
group by id_1
order by id_1;

      ID_1 MAX(UTC_TIMESTAMP)                   COUNT_1    COUNT_2
---------- --------------------------------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-07-24 15:41:36.000000 +00:00          2          3
       303 2017-07-24 15:41:55.000000 +00:00          4          0
      1461 2017-07-24 15:42:48.000000 +00:00          1          7
```

And then for your next step:

```
select max(max_utc_timestamp) as max_utc_timestamp,
  sum(count_1) as sum_count_1,
  sum(count_2) as sum_count_2
from (
  select max(utc_timestamp) as max_utc_timestamp,
    max(count_1) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_1,
    max(count_2) keep (dense_rank last order by utc_timestamp) as count_2
  from table_name
  where utc_timestamp > timestamp '2017-07-24 16:40:00 Europe/London' -- current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
  and utc_timestamp <= timestamp '2017-07-24 16:45:00 Europe/London' -- current_timestamp
  group by id_1
);

MAX_UTC_TIMESTAMP                 SUM_COUNT_1 SUM_COUNT_2
--------------------------------- ----------- -----------
2017-07-24 15:42:48.000000 +00:00           7          10
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex. I should have mentioned this in my post. Combination of ID_1, ID_2, ID_3 and SERVER_NAME is unique. I am trying to use your version of SQL and will let you know how it goes. Also I am doing sum(count_1) and sum(count_2). It won't make much difference here I guess but just wanted to mention.

Comment: @300 - isn't that just simple aggregation then? You want the max timestamp and the sum of both counts, for each unique combination of id_1/id_2/id_3/server_name?

Comment: No, only count_1 and count_2 are actual numbers that I want to sum on, but id_1, id_2 and id_3 are identifiers. ID_2 is even a varchar which has alphanumeric entries. I'll try to post a dummy subset of data.